# how do I solve this error shown after installing kivy on mac os x yosemite?

Tags: python, macos, syntax-error, kivy

I have installed Kivy on my mac with os x Yosemite 10.10 and have 2 versions of Python installed on my mac (2.7 and 3) and kivy 1.9

Whenever I try to Launch an example application this error shows up:

```
>>> kivy camera.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    kivy camera.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

The application code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
'''
Application example using build() + return
==========================================

An application can be built if you return a widget on build(), or if you set
self.root.
'''

import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # return a Button() as a root widget
        return Button(text='hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I have had a hard time installing all its dependencies, Please let me know if theres a way to go around this, I am relatively new to this framework.

Comment: I am confused. You typed `kivy camera.py` inside a Python interactive shell?

Comment: *"have 2 versions of java installed on my mac"* -> I think you mean 2 versions of Python?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run the program from python command prompt?

To launch the python program run

```
python camera.py
```

from your terminal